# How to start ant build with log4j 2?

Tags: logging, ant, build, log4j, log4j2

I have already started a ant build with **log4j-1.2.15.jar**.
Here the content of my **start.sh**:

```
ant -e -listener org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener -lib ./log4j
```

So, that was easy ;)

**?** I have cleared out the log4j folder and put the new log4j-core-2.3.jar in there. I have not added a [custom config](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html). I run the following command again

```
ant -e -listener org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener -lib ./log4j
```

and get the following message

> BUILD FAILED
>   Class org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener could not be loaded  because of an invalid dependency.

what can I do? Thank you

-- UPDATE 20. Juli 2015:

```
BUILD FAILED
Class org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener could not be loaded because of an invalid dependency.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ClasspathUtils.newInstance(ClasspathUtils.java:265)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.addBuildListeners(Main.java:937)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:772)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener.<init>(Log4jListener.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ClasspathUtils.newInstance(ClasspathUtils.java:250)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 12 more
```

BONUS:
How can I get rid of the ant echo in my console. As you can see, I have already add the **-e** option. So the [echo] tag is gone but the message is still in there.

-- Update(2) 20. Juli 2015

The "[Migrating from Log4j 1.x - Apache Log4j 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avlkO.png)" guide says:

> The main package in version 1 is org.apache.log4j, in version 2 it is org.apache.logging.log4j

so I guess the `org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener` is looking at the wrong place.

How to say `Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.5 compiled on May 31 2015` to use a other package?

Comment: Add the `-verbose` option to your `ant` command. Then, edit your question to add the entire stack trace that shows the error message.

Answer (score 1):

`Log4jListener` depends on log4j 1.x. It cannot use the newer log4j 2.x.

[Download the latest zip file of log4j 1.2.x](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html) from Apache. Open the archive and extract log4j-1.2.*.jar to the `log4j` directory that your `-lib` option points to.

Comment: As I said, log4j 1.x does work pretty well. Is there any way to use log4j v2? I like to use the highlight feature!!

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a way to use log4j v2 with `Log4jListener`.